# Write up on preparation for pursuing a PhD degree in your subject of interest

Tags: phd, statement-of-purpose, motivation

I am applying Ph.D. in Mathematics. In the form I found the question.

> Please write about your preparation for pursuing a PhD degree in your subject of interest?

How should I write the answer? What should be the answer for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form is a general one from the graduate school write about your background (preparation) in mathematics generally. If the form is from the math department then it needs to be more specific. If you want to study, say, algebraic geometry, then write about your courses, readings, research, etc. in that and related fields. Mention any publications, of course.

In other words, what have you done that prepares you to begin advanced study in your subject.

It might also be evaluated as a writing sample, I'd guess, so make it literate.